# SSL on site which asks API via HTTPS

Tags: https, api

For example I have a site `example.com`. It has its own HTTP JSON API: `api.example.com`. API has authorisation and it runs under `https://`.

I need to make visualization of some functionality of JSON API - so I need to make a profile section on `example.com`:
Authorisation form, and user profile section with actions.

All actions will be done via cURL requests to `https://api.example.com`.

Do I need to use SSL on `example.com` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the server to server communication, it's not really necessary to run SSL on `example.com`, since the communication it makes with `api.example.com` will be encrypted and the identity of `api.example.com` will be trusted (using its certificate). If the main site must authenticate itself with the API subdomain, however, it's a good idea to use SSL there too (although other forms of authentication are possible).

From the end-user perspective, however, things are different: since the browser is communicating to the main site using simple `http` it can expect no protection against [MitM attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), so any data exchanged this way can be read or manipulated by a malicious third-party. This wouldn't be a problem if this data were public and unimportant, but from what I understood the "user profile" involves credentials (authorization - or would it be authentication?) and other actions which I believe should be restricted to that particular user. In that case, use of SSL in `example.com` is really necessary.

P.S. If the **browser** is the one accessing `api.example.com`, then in principle it wouldn't be a problem - since all communication would be done securely - but OTOH you can't trust **the code** in your page, since it came from an unprotected `example.com`. In the end, only having the top level site using SSL would ensure proper security (and ideally, no untrusted content should be mixed in).